# VOLTTRON Simple Web agent

Tags: volttron

On release 8.1.1 I am trying to experiment with the [simple web agent](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/releases-6.x/devguides/walkthroughs/Simple-WebAgent-Walkthrough.html).

Running through the setup process

```
volttron -vv -l volttron.log --bind-web-address http://0.0.0.0:8080 &
```

Everything seem to install OK for `http` protrocol on the `vcfg` and starting the agent starts fine but going to the browser I get an empty page response.

And in terminal an error here's the Full traceback:

.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed] at 0x7f64342242c)> failed with SSLError

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 34, in _handle_and_close_when_done
return handle(*args_tuple)
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 233, in wrap_socket_and_handle
with _closing_socket(self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)) as ssl_socket:
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 793, in wrap_socket
return SSLSocket(sock=sock, keyfile=keyfile, certfile=certfile,
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 311, in **init**
raise x
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 307, in **init**
self.do_handshake()
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 663, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:1131)
2021-09-29T13:38:34Z <Greenlet at 0x7f64341fc480: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method StreamServer.wrap_socket_and_handle , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed] at 0x7f643419195)> failed with SSLError

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 34, in _handle_and_close_when_done
return handle(*args_tuple)
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 233, in wrap_socket_and_handle
with _closing_socket(self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)) as ssl_socket:
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 793, in wrap_socket
return SSLSocket(sock=sock, keyfile=keyfile, certfile=certfile,
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 311, in **init**
raise x
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 307, in **init**
self.do_handshake()
File "/home/ben/Desktop/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 663, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:1131)
2021-09-29T13:38:34Z <Greenlet at 0x7f643423c6a0: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method StreamServer.wrap_socket_and_handle , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed] at 0x7f64342242c)> failed with SSLError

***EDIT***

So if I do a `nano ~/.volttron/config` it looks like this below. I did change the `bind-web-address` for the IP address of my test bench instance. Hopefully that wasn't a mistake it looked like the initial `bind-web-address` was the name of the computer. `--bind-web-address http://ben-hp-probook-6550b:8080`

```
message-bus = zmq
vip-address = tcp://127.0.0.1:22916
instance-name = benshome
bind-web-address = http://192.168.0.105:8080
web-ssl-cert = /home/ben/.volttron/certificates/certs/platform_web-server.crt
web-ssl-key = /home/ben/.volttron/certificates/private/platform_web-server.pem
web-secret-key = 0e3b19770c0a8c0a08f274fcdabaf939fecc16601283266934c5ab258a1ed20cf440fde2c83cb8660dac569d31b5cdaf3ab7354a39b0640f355f9c5407c5fce619
```

I think I did first try HTTPS then resorted to HTTP. Anyways when I start VOLTTRON do I still need a `--bind-web-address` arg if the `~/.volttron/config` is already setup with one?

I've a tried both when starting VOLTTRON to use the --bind flag or not but still unable to bring up a webpage on the IP address of the machine running VOLTTRON of 192.168.0.105. This would be the simple web agent, right?

Comment: Remove the web--ssl-cert and web-ssl-key  (or comment them out with a # on the front of the line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this when I ran through vcfg and specified https, but then did what you did and passed the bind-web-address to the volttron command itself.

However, you shouldn't do this.  The instructions assume you haven't gone through the vcfg process and therefore you would have to specify the bind web address on the command line.

Since you went through the vcfg process your config file (~/.volttron/config) will have your hostname:port as the bind-web-address.  If it has https in it that is the reason it is not working for you.